# Nested dictionary from a txt with the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I have a txt file with the dictionary like this:

```
{'origin': {'Ukraine': 50, 'Portugal': 20, 'others': 10}, 'native language': {'ucranian': 50; 'english': 45, 'russian': 30, 'others': 10}, 'second language': {'ucranian': 50; 'english': 45, 'russian': 30, 'others': 10, 'none': 0}, 'profession': {'medical doctor': 50, 'healthcare professional': 40, 'cooker': 30, 'others': 10, 'spy': 0}, 'first aid skills': {'yes': 50, 'no': 0}, 'driving skills': {'yes': 40, 'no': 0}, 'cooking skills': {'yes': 50, 'some': 30, 'no': 0}, 'IT skills': {'yes': 50, 'little': 35, 'no': 0}}
```

And I want to create a dictionary from this

I tried using `ast.literal_eval` but it gives me the [following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevlu.jpg)

```
SyntaxError: expression expected after dictionary key and ':'
```

This is my code :

```
def helpersSkills(helpersFile, skillsFile):
    """
    """
    helpers = open(helpersFile, 'r')
    skills = open(skillsFile, 'r')
    skillsLines = skills.read()
    dictionary = ast.literal_eval(skillsLines)

 
 ...

helpersSkills('helpersArrived2.txt', 'skills.txt')
```

Comment: use json for it to work

Comment: `others` lacks quotes in all of your dicts. Can't you get the data in a better, more coherent shape, like for example valid JSON? If you can't, you could try replacing `others` by `'others'` before using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @LeylaZwolinski Two problems for that: some keys are not quoted, and JSON requires double, not single quotes.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille sorry I pasted the older version of the txt, but yes I already changed it to 'others' and the error is exactly the same.

Comment: There are also semicolons instead of commas at some places. Please provide **valid** sample input. Has your data been written by hand to contain so many errors??

Comment: yes i was required to use a txt writen by a professor, and you were rigth i didnt notice the ; .
thanks for the help! was an easy fix and a stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said by @ThierryLathuille it was just some writing errors in the txt file
so its working:

```
{'origin': {'Ukraine': 50, 'Portugal': 20, 'others': 10}, 'native language': {'ucranian': 50, 'english': 45, 'russian': 30, 'others': 10}, 'second language': {'ucranian': 50, 'english': 45, 'russian': 30, 'others': 10, 'none': 0}, 'profession': {'medical doctor': 50, 'healthcare professional': 40, 'cooker': 30, 'others': 10, 'spy': 0}, 'first aid skills': {'yes': 50, 'no': 0}, 'driving skills': {'yes': 40, 'no': 0}, 'cooking skills': {'yes': 50, 'some': 30, 'no': 0}, 'IT skills': {'yes': 50, 'little': 35, 'no': 0}}
```

This is the code :

```
def helpersSkills(helpersFile, skillsFile):
    """
    """
    helpers = open(helpersFile, 'r')
    skills = open(skillsFile, 'r')
    skillsLines = skills.read()
    dictionary = ast.literal_eval(skillsLines)

 
 ...

helpersSkills('helpersArrived2.txt', 'skills.txt')
```